# How can I trace gcp pubsub like tracing an HTTP request?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, trace, google-cloud-trace

I have multiple apps written in nodejs.

I am trying to monitor the apps using [google-trace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/trace-agent). I am able to get traces successfully for the HTTP requests. But I have some apps which are pulling events from pubsub subscriptions, so that is out of the HTTP request-response. I also have some cloud functions which are triggered by the firestore collections, even those executions are not getting traced.

The google-trace package doesn't automatically trace pubsub thing. It says it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/trace-agent#what-gets-traced).

What I am trying to do is add a custom span in my pubsub-subscription-worker [this way](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/trace-agent#usage)

Is it possible to trace the pubsub events using google-trace? If yes, what am I missing?

If not, is it possible to do so via any other monitoring/APM?